# How to read a file line by line then take each line and insert into txt file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

I want to read each line of a file and then take each line and produce a file with the lines data in it.

For example let say the file I want to read is named txt.txt and it has the below 4 lines:

```
data for the first row
data for the second row
data for the third row
data for the fourth row
```

I would like to produce 4 output files, each with a single line from the input file. So there would be 4 files that are produced after reading the input file. One named text1.txt (it would have the first line of data in it), one named text2.txt (it would have the second line of data in it), and so on.

Comment: `split -l1 text inputfile`.

Comment: Have you tried researching this? Reading a file one line at a time and output redirection is very common and there are a lot of resources online.

Answer (score 1):

One simple answer would be:

```
awk '{ print > "text"NR".txt"}' < input
```

This prints every line to a file that's named with your pattern; `NR` is a special variable in awk that contains the current line number.

With GNU split:

```
split -l1 --additional-suffix=.txt --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=1 input text
```

This splits the input file `input` one line at a time (`-l1`) into files with a prefix of `text`, with an additional suffix of `.txt`, with numeric suffixes starting at one and with no padding. Note that this method is limited to nine lines of input. If your filenames are flexible, you could drop the `--suffix-length=1` option and the filenames would be named `text01.txt .. text11.txt ...`, which would get you up to 99 lines.